# AngularJS radio button group with select list value

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have an AngularJS app which asks the user to input a number from some options using a radio button group to indicate their choice.

There are 3 fixed options (with values 1, 2 and 3 for example), and a fourth option which contains a select list with the additional option values 4, 5, 6. The fixed values are common enough to separate them but we want to be able to give alternate options.

Everything is fine without the select list as the 4th option, but I am having trouble with handling the 2 separate values for the radio button value and the value of the select list.

Ideally, the markup for this situation is something like

```
<!-- Controller aliased as ctrl-->    

<!-- Fixed Option 1-->
<label>
    <input type="radio" name="selectedNumber" ng-model="ctrl.SelectedNumber" ng-value="1"/>
    1
</label>
<!-- Fixed Option 2-->
<label>
    <input type="radio" name="selectedNumber" ng-model="ctrl.SelectedNumber" ng-value="2"/>
    2
</label>
<!-- Fixed Option 3-->
<label>
    <input type="radio" name="selectedNumber" ng-model="ctrl.SelectedNumber" ng-value="3"/>
    3
</label>

<!-- Custom Option-->
<label>
    <input type="radio" name="selectedNumber" ng-model="ctrl.SelectedNumber" ng-value="?"/>
    <select ng-model="ctrl.SelectedNumber" ng-options="option for option in [4, 5, 6]"></select>
</label>
```

With a controller that looks like

```
...
var ctrl = this;
ctrl.SelectedNumber = 1;
...
```

**My question is this: how can I keep track of the state of the radio button group and the state of the select list to bind to a single selected option?**

A jsFiddle can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jh423yur/5/). Thank you!

Comment: The jsFiddle seems to work. Do you just want the radio button to just _appear_ to be selected?

Comment: Why do you even need fourth radio?

Comment: @jperezov, Yes I do want the radio button to appear selected. It is the interplay between the ng-value of the 4th radio button, the ng-model on all of the radio buttons, and the ng-model on the select list I am having trouble with. Am I just way over-complicating this? Thanks for looking at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to have the select field update the radio button, you actually need to have its model be a different variable, and use `$scope.$watch` to sync them. [Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/jh423yur/8/).

This is what your updated controller should look like:

```
var ctrl = this;
ctrl.SelectedNumber = 1;
ctrl.selectVal = 4;
$scope.$watch('ctrl.selectVal', function(val) {
  ctrl.SelectedNumber = val;
});
```

And your updated HTML (just the last radio button / select):

```
 <input type="radio" name="selectedNumber" ng-model="ctrl.SelectedNumber" ng-value="ctrl.selectVal" />
 <select ng-model="ctrl.selectVal" ng-options="option for option in [4, 5, 6]"></select>
```

The `ng-value` of the radio button becomes the `ng-model` of the select.

Comment: Thank you. That is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Also you can call a function for select list change to select last radio button. Like..

*HTML*

```
<label>
    <input type="radio" name="selectedNumber" ng-model="ctrl.SelectedNumber" value="{{ctrl.selectval}}" />
    <select ng-model="ctrl.selectval" ng-change="ctrl.selectFromList(ctrl.selectval)" ng-options="option for option in [4, 5, 6]"></select>
  </label>
```

*and controller:*

```
app.controller("MainCtrl", function() {
    var ctrl = this;
    ctrl.SelectedNumber = 1;
    ctrl.selectval=4;
    ctrl.selectFromList = function(getVal) {
      ctrl.SelectedNumber = getVal;
    };
  });
```